# Given a binary random matrix A, M rows & N columns, how many non-zero binary column vectors b (Z 1's, Z <<N) exist so mod(A*b,2) = all zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The matrix $\mathbf A$ is a binary random matrix, M by N.  One's and zeros equally likely. $\mathbf A$ is a full rank matrix.  I form the GF2 product mod($\mathbf A \mathbf b,2$) with a binary column vector $\mathbf b$ (N elements), containing Z one's.  Assume Z << N, but of course $Z > 0$. How many vectors b exist such that mod($\mathbf A \mathbf b,2) = 0$?

Assuming such vectors exist, is there a way to compute them, or will a computer search be required to find them?